# How to extend Ruby ERB for handling %= tags as well?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, erb

I am using ERB for metaprogramming of some math language. If I could extend ERB functionality to handle `%=` tags, it would allow me to simplify my sources significantly. I simply want to get output of the line in analogy with `<%= %>`. I have tried to dig into `/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb` file, but got lost very quickly. May be you can help with this problem?

Comment: Maybe you could clarify? What's wrong with using <%= %>?

Comment: Three unnecessary characters, which make code-reading significantly harder unless I shadow them in TextMate theme/language settings. There is no need in `%` tag as well - one can use `<% %>`. The Ruby way, as I see it, is to maximize code beauty, and `%=` fits this concept very well. :)

Comment: Have you looked at HAML...? I'm not sure 'fixing' ERB is really the way to go here.

Comment: @Joe: I don't work with HTML, but with a math program which uses text files to input data. I need ERB to make those text files in a convenient way, and it does the job very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems I have managed it by myself. If you save the code at http://pastie.org/1056824 (or http://gist.github.com/487297) as `extended_erb.rb` and then call it in your script...

```
require 'extended_erb'
puts ERB.new(File.read('mytemplate.erb'), 0, '%').result
```

or run ERB from command line...

```
erb -r extended_erb  mytemplate.erb
```

then the following template...

```
<%= 1 %>
%= 2
```

will produce output desired

```
1
2
```